# how to download a file by just visiting a website?

Tags: antivirus

I'm talking about getting a file download to computer without letting user know any files have downloaded, just like a virus.  Some virus are getting downloaded without asking a user if you wanna download a file it just download it self.  I'm trying to create an simple antivirus.  How do they do that

Comment: it sounds more like you're creating a simple *virus* than a simple anti-virus...creating an antivirus program is a huge undertaking!

Comment: well...When i know how to create the virus i know how to stop it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I would think that this could be done is by exploiting a buffer overflow and executing arbitrary code once the stack's been smashed (to execute the file download).

Having said that, I **very** highly doubt you'd be able to find any present day browsers that have any such vulnerabilities. These days, browser-caused viruses (virii? ;)) only run rampant on systems that have users that execute the downloads/installs manually.

Edit: I'll also mention that actually getting this to work takes a high level of skill (as the "arbitrary" code is usually processor-specific assembly instructions). It takes an even higher level of skill and knowledge to protect against it.

Answer (score 0):

nope you cannot do that. even the virus they need to be executed after downloaded. 
as far as i know, when I did browse some web I just got cookies that contains spying me when I clicked on some websites. cmiiw

Answer (score -1):

Maybe parsing your program to javascript and inserting to your site?

Or insert to another site and then put an iframe in your site to avoid blacklisting by AVs.

---

Aso I have read somewhere that WMF-files can be exploited.